# add_rewrite_tag works for some parameters but does not for others

Tags: url-rewriting

I have created this new rewrite rule but it matches some patterns but does not match others when both are identical. For example:

for `category/resources/newsletters/2017` it loads `category-newsletters.php` but for `category/resources/newsletters/2014` i see 404 page.

(I generate permalink structure everytime i change rewrite rule)

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');

function cd_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^category/resources/newsletters/([0-9]+)/?','index.php?category_name=newsletters&year=$matches[1]','top');

    add_rewrite_tag('%year%', '([0-9]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'my123_rewrite_rule');
```

Using debug plugin I have found that different query strings are being applied for same pattern requests.

`category/resources/newsletters/2017  => year=2017&category_name=newsletters`

`category/resources/newsletters/2014  => category_name=newsletters&name=2014`

Comment: It sounds like you have conflicting terms - for example you have a taxonomy called `name` that contains year values, but also `year` that contains year values. The safest way to proceed is to consolidate so you don't have any terms with duplicate slugs. Otherwise WP will continue to get confused about which one you're requesting.

Comment: Sorry forgot to update here. I changed parameter year to something else and it started working. You can answer this question and i will mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have conflicting terms - for example you have a taxonomy called name that contains year values, but also year that contains year values. The safest way to proceed is to consolidate so you don't have any terms with duplicate slugs. Otherwise WP will continue to get confused about which one you're requesting.